# Split columns based on patterns in fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

Example: I'd like to split `$2` in input file, putting a `tab` after pattern `surname`

Input:

```
name    surname1    
name    surname30000
name    surname456
```

Desired output:

```
name    surname    1
name    surname    30000
name    surname    456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **awk** alternative:

```
awk 'match($2,/[0-9]+$/) {printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, substr($2,0,RSTART), substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH))}' filename
```

This will match only the numeric string at the end of the second column.

Answer (score 2):

You can lookup the first digit and replace it by a tab followed by the digit using:

```
sed 's/[0-9]/\t&/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]\)/\t\1/' input.txt
```

adds a tab before the first digit on every line.

Output:

```
name    surname 1    
name    surname 30000
name    surname 456
```

Answer (score 2):

The data might be in a specific *column*, e.g., 16:

```
sed -e 's/^\(.\{15,15\}\)/\1 /'
```

Alternatively, the data of interest in the third field may not be numeric:

```
sed -e 's/^\([[:alpha:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/\1\2 /'
```

Either of these will put a space before the digits (or other non-alphabetic) characters in the data.

For reference:

- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)